# How to get the distinguished name (DN) of the current host directly in adedit?

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, tcl

I know how to get the DN from the command line:

```
adquery user -D "$(hostname -s)"
```

However, I want to get the DN into an adedit script.  If I can `select_object {DN here}`, then I can do the other things I need to do.

I just don't know how to get the DN directly in `adedit`.

---

According to the `adquery` man page (part of the Centrify Suite):

> The  adquery  command is provided for backward compatibility to enable you to query Active Directory for information about users and groups from the command line on a Centrify-managed computer. You can use this command to query information for classic or hierarchical zones. In most cases, however, you should use adedit commands or scripts
>          to query Active Directory for information in hierarchical zones.

However, there is no clear documentation I can find on how to translate `adquery` commands into native calls within `adedit`.

For example:

```
adquery user `hostname -s` --dump
```

This gives a list of all the raw attributes and values for the user that is the computer I'm running the command on.  Using the `--attribute` flag, I can return just one attribute.

With `adedit`, after I've run `select_object THE_DN`, I can get other fields such as "description" by running `get_object_field description`.  But, how to get the DN in the first place?

I've found the [adedit programmer's guide](https://docs.centrify.com/en/css/suite2016/centrify-adedit-guide.pdf), but can't find what I need in there despite extensive digging and experimentation.

---

Until I get a better approach, I am running:

```
adedit myscript "$(adquery user -D "$(hostname -s)")"
```

And then in the script:

```
if { $argc != 1 } {
  puts "format: $argv0 hostDN"
  exit 1
}

set the_dn [lindex $argv 0]

bind ... (credentials here)

select_object $the_dn
```

---

(Note: adedit is built on Tcl, so I've tagged this question Tcl as well as Active Directory.  I don't have the reputation to create a Centrify tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any Centrify hosts to test with at the moment. But I'm guessing what you're looking for is a combination of `get_adinfo host` and `get_objects`.

`get_adinfo host` will give you the current host's info or at least a computer name (memory hazy).

`get_objects` more of a generic LDAP query command that takes typical LDAP parameters like depth, base (DN), and filter.

So once you have the computer name, you can use `get_objects` to query the DN something like this.

```
set results [get_objects -depth sub "DC=example,DC=com" "(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=$hostname))"]
set compDN [lindex $results 0]
```

Again, totally untested. But I'm pretty sure this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Ryan!  I had tried `get_adinfo host` and it only gives the hostname, not the DN, etc.  I am away from the office now but I will try `get_objects` when I return—I had found it in the manual, but couldn't figure out the filter syntax.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's standard LDAP filter syntax. But if you don't have much experience running LDAP queries, it's pretty weird at first. There are tons of guides online though.

Comment: That `get_objects` command does indeed work!  However, for whatever reason, I need a `$` at the end of the hostname.  I confirmed this by selecting a host's object and checking `get_object_field_names` and then `get_object_field sAMAccountName` and the result was `{thehostname$}`.  So I put the `$` in the search and it then worked.